# border-radius and box-shadow not working as expected

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using bootstrap-vue in my project and I am using the responsive grid. I have used different cols sizes for different view points. I am having a issue to add background, border-radius and box-shadow to the content of the `<b-row>`, since width of the `<b-row>` is more than the width of all columns. So I add the background for each column and its working fine (I am not sure its the correct way to do it). I used the same method to add the border-radius. Its working fine in until cols get stacked each other in small devices. I couldn't make box-shadow working for any device size. Is there any way I can wrap the content inside the `<b-row>` and add border-radius and box-shadow and the background to the wrapper.

example https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-goldstine-wwpng?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@media query` to resolve your issue. and I suggest avoid to use inline style.